# split a time series by another irregular time series

Tags: r, split, xts

I am trying to split several xts objects with one unique irregular time series.  `split.xts` splits on days, minutes, seconds, etc. Using breakpoints requires vectors of equal length, which produces an error when I try to split my data.

```
dd <- c("2014-02-23","2014-03-12", "2014-05-29")
tt <- c("03:15:52", "03:49:17", "04:03:24", "05:30:19", "05:56:49",
        "06:14:04", "09:42:13", "11:57:25", "11:58:02", "12:12:49",
        "15:38:00", "15:44:21", "16:16:04")
dt <- c(outer(dd,tt,paste))
xx <- as.xts(seq_along(dt), as.POSIXct(dt))
spltr <- c("2014-01-13 12:09:32", "2014-02-09 06:23:41",
           "2014-03-01 13:35:12", "2014-05-14 07:12:52")
```

I am trying to split `xx` by `spltr` to find the frequency of records in each piece.
I tried `aggregate(xx,by=spltr,length)` but I get an error because `spltr` is not the same length as `xx`.  `split.xts` doesn't work because `spltr` is not regular.

Comment: sorry my tt vector is missing the first parenthesis tt <- c(...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, merge your `xx` object with an empty xts object containing your breakpoints.

```
xs <- merge(xx, xts(,as.POSIXct(spltr)))
```

Then you can find the 'endpoints' of your `spltr` object in `xs` by using the `which.i` argument to `[.xts`.

```
ep <- c(0,xs[as.POSIXct(spltr),which.i=TRUE])
```

Now you can use `period.apply` on the `xs` object (making sure to deal with any potential `NA`).

```
> period.apply(xs, ep, function(x) nrow(na.omit(x)))
                    xx
2014-01-13 12:09:32  0
2014-02-09 06:23:41  0
2014-03-01 13:35:12 13
2014-05-14 07:12:52 13
```

Comment: If you are as puzzled as me about `which.i`, than check out `?"[.xls"`. First time I read about this... In fact, there are many other [. examples in the help files.