# How do I subset irregular, intraday financial data in R using conditional price points?

Tags: r, time-series, xts, finance

I have some financial tick data, `head(df_xts)`:

```
                     price volume
2016-06-01 09:30:00  1073      1
2016-06-01 09:30:00  1073      1
2016-06-01 09:30:00  1073      1
2016-06-01 09:30:00  1073      1
2016-06-01 09:30:00  1073      1
2016-06-01 09:30:00  1073      5
```

I want to look at this data after price has moved a certain distance above its opening range. I define the opening range as the first 15 minutes:

```
df_open <- df_xts["T09:30/T09:44"]
```

(`df_main`, which is referenced below, is the remaining time frame of the day.)

The following finds the max price, or "opening range high" for each day:

```
orh <- apply.daily(df_open$price, max)
> orh
                      price
2016-06-01 09:44:55 1083.75
2016-06-02 09:44:59 1119.25
2016-06-03 09:44:59 1169.00
2016-06-06 09:44:53 1155.00
```

and this finds the price at a pre-defined `breakout` distance above the opening range high:

```
orh_bo <- orh + breakout
```

I then find the first observation of each day where price has moved up to this breakout point, which gives me the index value of the "breakout", relative to the day:

```
orh_bo_index <- apply.daily(df_main, FUN = function(X) first(which(X %in% orh_bo)))
> orh_bo_index
                     [,1]
2016-06-01 14:14:59  2074
2016-06-02 14:14:59 10693
2016-06-03 14:14:59  2351
2016-06-06 14:14:59  1224

orh_bo_matrix <- coredata(orh_bo_index)
```

I combine this breakout index with an index of daily endpoints to create a data frame, `df_bo_indexes`:

```
ep_daily <- endpoints(df_main, on = "days")
daily_last_index <- ep_daily[-1]
daily_last_matrix <- t(t(daily_last_index))
df_bo_indexes <- bind_cols(data.frame(orh_bo_matrix), data.frame(daily_last_matrix))

> df_bo_indexes
  orh_bo_matrix daily_last_matrix
1          2074             52155
2         10693            126623
3          2351            181408
4          1224            221002
```

How do I subset the data using the above indexes? This is what I have tried so far:

```
df_bo_day1 <- df_main[df_bo_indexes[1,1]:df_bo_indexes[1,2]]
i <- 2
for(i in 2:ndays(df_main)) {
df_bo_all <- df_main[(df_bo_indexes[i-1,2]+df_bo_indexes[i,1]):df_bo_indexes[i,2]]
}
```

[split a time series by another irregular time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831745/split-a-time-series-by-another-irregular-time-series]) was useful, but I'm not sure how to apply this to intraday data.

My full code and data set can be found at https://github.com/blottb7/tick-data. I am interested in anyone who has worked on time series' inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I `split(), lapply(,cummax), do.call(rbind,), merge()` for the opening range. Did the same for entire data frame. Merged the opening range with entire range. Then used `breakout <- ifelse(cummax - breakout > opening_range_cummax, TRUE, FALSE), then subset by breakout == 1`.